# Execution of SQL statement in Java function

Tags: java, sql

I have to read the below SQL statement from one properties.

```
update  scoreconfig  set scorestatus=0 where scoreversion=props.getProperty("scoreversion");
```

And value for score version I've to take it from other properties file.

But, when I prepare a statement in java function as below:

```
final String query = strLine;
PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(query);
```

where `query` has

```
update  scoreconfig  set scorestatus=0 where scoreversion=props.getProperty("scoreversion");
```

But I get

```
Error: ORA-00911: invalid character
```

...when I do `ps.execute();`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When you were asking your question, there was a `[?]` link above the question textbox and a `How to Format` box to the right of it, listing amongst other things how you mark up code to make it readable in the question. Well worth a read. I was about to fix it for you, but rsp beat me to it. :-)

Comment: `@user829710` **Welcome to StackOverflow!** I recommend you to change your username.

Comment: @jmendeth: I think your edit goes a bit too far. (Just my opinion, others may differ.) rsp's looks fine other than putting the "where query =" bit in the code block.

Comment: I think the `where query has = ...` is **not** part of the java code; the author wanted to say: _In the avobe code, the `query` variable contains the previously readen SQL (`update scoreconfig  set scorestatus ...`)_ (This is why I replaced it with a comment) Don't you think that?

Comment: @jmendeth: I do indeed, that's why I said that about rsp's version. I've updated it now that the pending edit is gone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume `props` is a [`Properties`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) instance or similar. If so, the `props.getProperty("scoreversion")` part is meant to happen at the Java layer, not in the database. Instead:

```
String sql = "update scoreconfig set scorestatus=0 where scoreversion=?";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
// If scoreversion is a String:
ps.setString(1, props.getProperty("scoreversion"));
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

...or if scoreversion is an int, use this instead of the `setString` line:

```
// It scoreversion is an int:
ps.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty("scoreversion")));
```

...etc., convert as appropriate.

Basically, when you use [`prepareStatement`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement%28java.lang.String%29), you use `?` where parameters should go, and then you use `setXyz` on the [`PreparedStatement`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instance to set those parameters. (Oddly, they start with `1`, not `0`.) Note that even when the parameter is a String, you *don't* put quotes around it in the SQL you pass into `prepareStatement`; that's handled for you (along with properly escaping that string to prevent [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), so `PreparedStatement` and `setXyz` are your friends, you'll get to know them well).